# Error Handling in Queries of Access #Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am working on a Attendance table in Access, where I have `InTime` and `OutTime`. These fields are of Date/Time Field.
Some records contains only Time like `11:40:00`, some contain Date as well as time like `21-07-2015 11:45:00`. Hence have used the below code for getting hours  worked.

```
HrsPresent: Round(DateDiff("n",TimeValue(TimeSerial(Hour([TimeIn]),Minute([TimeIn]),Second([TimeIn]))),TimeValue(TimeSerial(Hour([TimeOut]),Minute([TimeOut]),Second([TimeOut]))))/60,2)
```

Using this above code, in a Column in making query gives correct Number of hours worked, but if any of the field is blank, i get `#error` in result.

I have tried using `Nz` , `IsError`, `IsNumeric` but all in Vain.

- What is it that, I am doing wrong?
- Is other way of getting hours worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to make sure that both of the needed fields aren't blank before performing your calculation. You could do this using two `IIF` statements.  If one field is blank then you simply assign a default value or handle it how you want.

In my example the default is zero, I have to warn you though this was done free hand and I am not super confident that my brackets line up properly. Also I am sorry that it is all on one line, I couldn't think of a logical way to break it down.

```
HrsPresent: IIF(Nz([TimeIn],"") = "", 0, IIF(Nz([TimeOut],"") = "", 0, Round(DateDiff("n",TimeValue(TimeSerial(Hour([TimeIn]),Minute([TimeIn]),Second([TimeIn]))),TimeValue(TimeSerial(Hour([TimeOut]),Minute([TimeOut]),Second([TimeOut]))))/60,2)))
```

For more information on `IIF` statements you can use visit here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

Comment: Thanks so much, Now understood, where to add `Nz`. I was adding to whole function.